# How do I make an application start only in XFCE?

Tags: xfce, autostart

I would like to have an application (most likely AWN or Docky) start only on XFCE, and not on KDE or Unity/GNOME. Is this possible? If so, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the following script, replacing `launch_app` with the command that launches the application you want to launch at session start.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$DESKTOP_SESSION" = "xfce" ]; then
    launch_app
fi
```

Give the script executable privileges with `chmod +x`, then tell your autostart configuration tool (not sure what XFCE uses) to use that script.

Should work.